# Multiple User Streams in Twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am have been stuck on this since last week. For some reason, only my stream is Printed. Here is some of my Code:

```
twitterStream.user(new String[] {"username1", "username2"});
```

When i do this, i only gets mine? I am not sure why, i needed to get both users streams, then in the

```
@Override
public void onStatus(Status status) {
    // Get Data
}
```

For some reason, this only gets my stream, like followers tweets etc. How do i get username's 2 stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because [`TwitterStream#user(String[])`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#user%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) accepts **keywords** to track and not user names. The [user stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user) only streams events for the currently authenticated user.

You will have to start another user stream to get events for a second user.

This is what [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user#Connections) has to say about multiple user streams:

> Minimize the number of connections your application makes to User
>   Streams. Each Twitter account is limited to only a few simultaneous
>   User Streams connections per OAuth application, regardless of IP. Once
>   the per-application limit is exceeded, the oldest connection will be
>   terminated. An account logging in from too many instances of the same
>   OAuth application will cycle connections as the application instances
>   reconnect and disconnect each other.

Note that it might be better to use a [site stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/site) if you want to connect on behalf of more users, however it appears to be in limited beta-testing presently.

**EDIT:**

The track parameter is also matched against the screen name, see the [`track` parameter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track) for more information.

Comment: Ok. I thought that i the String[] was for users to track. How many streams can i open per user?

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a bit misleading. There's a [discussion here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6268) that goes into simultaneous user stream connections - there doesn't seem to be any hard and fast rules though.

Comment: But when i add the username to the .User(), even if the username is not in the tweet it shows up?

Comment: @EliteGamer I've updated my answer - `screen_name` will also be matched by `track` parameters.